# How to swap ids in database using hibernate

Tags: mysql, image, hibernate, photo

I am storing images in file system and updating the image path in database.

**Table structure**

photo_id,user_id,photo_no,photo_url

Users can upload maximum of 5 photos. photo_no is the field where i store the order. The first photo will be always the main photo. But users can make any photo as main photo and they can also arrange the photo.

If the user wants to make the 3rd photo as main photo(photo_no 1). Then i have to update photo_no 3 to some dummy temp number and  update photo_no 1 with 3 and update temp number with 1. This way i can swap the photos. But i don't think this to be a good method. Can any suggest a good way to do that.

is possible to handle this situation with a good table design?

Answer (score 1):

If the photos order can remain the same I would suggest that you introduce a new flag (column). So you can have:

```
photo_id, user_id, photo_no, photo_url, is_main_photo
```

and just put 1 for the main photo and 0 for other photos.

Comment: Thanks. Photo order won't remain same but i can introduce a new column and maintain the order. 1,3 | 2, 1 | 3, 3 | 4, 5 | 5, 5 (Photo, order) - Here 2nd photo is the main photo. But not sure how to update the table if some changes the order.

Comment: If you really need to swap the photo_no of two photos, then the table design you have is sufficient.
You can use Hibernate to programatically swap order numbers.

I'm not sure how your persistence layer looks like, but you can do something like this:
`mainPhoto.setPhotoNo(futureMainPhoto.getPhotoNo());
futureMainPhoto.setPhotoNo(1);
entityManager.pesist(mainPhoto); 
entityManager.pesist(futureMainPhoto);`